# how to print the contents of terminal in textarea of GUI using swing

Tags: swing, user-interface

I am new to stack overflow.I am facing problem in printing the contents of terminal in textarea of GUI using swing.can someone help me out.

thanks in advance

Comment: This is too broad to be useful at all - post the specific question you have, rather than just "I need help"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Message Console](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) will help you out.

It will allow you do redirect all your `System.out.println(...)` statements to text component.